# Using a binary number in for loop comparison

Tags: c, for-loop, binary

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* left, *right;
}  node;

node* createNode(int data) {
  node* x = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  x->data = data;
  x->left = x->right = NULL;
  return x;
}

node * addNode(node* head, int data) {
  if (head == NULL)
    return createNode(data);

  node* temp = head;
  while (temp->right)
    temp = temp->right;

  temp->right = createNode(data);
  temp->right->left = temp;
  return head;
}

void printList(node* head) {
  node* temp = head;
  while (temp) {
    printf("%d ", temp-> data);
    temp = temp->right;
  }
}

int main() {

  node* head = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < 010; i++)
    head = addNode(head, i + 1);
  printList(head);
  return 0;
}
```

The following code produces output
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

I am not able to understand the working of for loop.I only wanted to check how the compiler would handle the leading zeroes while comparing.If I put more zeroes in the front , I get more nodes appended to the linked list.The number of nodes appended are always in power of two.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `010` is octal, not binary

Comment: 010 is 8 in octal system - https://www.includehelp.com/c/working-with-octal-values-in-c-programming-language.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't have binary integer literals.

Integer literals staring with a zero are [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers.